# How to remove rows from a data frame using a subset?

Tags: r

I have a column in a data frame called Retest_data that goes like this:

```
SFC
YU006UGD31092
YU006UGD31071
YU006UGD30152
YU006UGD25831
YU006UGD25831
YU006UGD25332
YU006UG922912
YU006UG922912
```

And what I want is to remove all instances of values that occur more than once. So dplyr functions like unique and distinct won't work for me.

I also have a list called Remove_SFC that has all the SFC values that occur more than once.
How can I use this list to remove all recurring values from my data?
Thanks.

Comment: _So dplyr functions like unique and distinct won't work for me._ Why can't you use `distinct()` or `unique()`?

Comment: Which format is this list of values? Is it a real R list or a data frame or an external csv? Please share an example.

Comment: @Martin Gal I assume because distinct() would keep the first occurence, but the TO might want to delete ALL occurences in case there are duplicates.

Comment: You can use `dplyr::anti_join(Retest_data, Remove_SFC, by="SFC")`.

Comment: @deschen Its a data frame similar to the example above but all the values are values that occur more than once in the original data frame

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(SFC = c("YU006UGD31092","YU006UGD31071",
                         "YU006UGD30152",
                         "YU006UGD25831",
                         "YU006UGD25831",
                         "YU006UGD25332" ,
                         "YU006UG922912",
                         "YU006UG922912"))
```

Code:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(SFC) %>% 
  filter(n() == 1)
```

Output:

```
  SFC          
  <chr>        
1 YU006UGD31092
2 YU006UGD31071
3 YU006UGD30152
4 YU006UGD25332
```

Edit:

If you have the list, you can also do:

```
df %>% 
  filter(!(SFC %in% Remove_SFC))
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you can use `dplyr`'s `anti_join`. `anti_join` return all rows from `df` without a match in `Remove_SFC`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  anti_join(data.frame(SFC=Remove_SFC))
```

which returns

```r
Joining, by = "SFC"
            SFC
1 YU006UGD31092
2 YU006UGD31071
3 YU006UGD30152
4 YU006UGD25332
```

**Data**

```r
Remove_SFC <- c("YU006UG922912", "YU006UGD25831")
```